# Windows Server 2008 send an alert using Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I want to send an alert with Powershell. But I want to know if there is another way to send an alert, other than email.

Thanks.

P.S. I can't send emails because I don't have an smtp server, and due to some policies, I can't install one either. Furthermore, the server does not have Internet connection.

Comment: You shouldn't need an SMTP server of your own to send email.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to write that the server does not have Internet connection.

Comment: The (theoretical) alert goes over the local network then to specific people?

Comment: Yes, I'd send the message over the LAN, to 3 persons.

Comment: You've told us what you can't do. It would be more than helpful of you could tell us what you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send alerts over your local network - without the use of an email server, the best thing I can think of is Net Message - there are limitations of course, but this should satisfy your requirements, and should work over any NT client - although you must have a domain controller for this to truly work properly so that there are no authentication issues.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-NetMessage-Net-Send-0459d235 - This is a script written by somebody smarter than myself that is capable of sending console messages across a local network without anything even resembling SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to "send an alert" if you have any alerting system to connect to.

You could:

- Sent a message into the Event logs, if they are monitored by any tool (using [New-EventLog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/20/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs.aspx) )
- Run [PSExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to cause something to happen on another computer, e.g. a sound file to play or a program to launch, maybe with help from [NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
- Use Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-WebRequest, if you have a webserver with an alerting web interface you can call
- [Send SNMP traps](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/snmpts/powershell10/), if you have an SNMP trap listener
- Use any of the .Net framework TCP/IP interfaces to send arbitrary network packets, e.g. [send Syslog messages](https://www.poshsecurity.com/blog/2014/7/1/sending-syslog-messages-from-powershell.html) to a syslog server

The problems with bodging up an alerting system using something like net message include: it's off by default since Windows XP era, it's likely blocked by Windows firewall/third party endpoint protection, if you miss a message there's no way to check what it said or have it alert you again.

If it's important to monitor, you'd be better off setting up a sensible monitoring system, e.g. something like [PRTG](https://www.paessler.com/prtg/download) has a free edition for up to 100 sensors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `msg` to message users. The following will message all users logged in to a remote PC:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $computer -scriptblock { msg * "Enter message here" }
```

Easily the simplest method of sending an alert to users if you just want to warn them you're doing maintenance or something.